# Custom Spinner view under Button

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a Button that, when clicked, calls a Spinner. The Spinner has a custom view but the layout goes in the middle of the page instead of under the Button.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

Instead it looks like this:

[image]

How can I show the view under my Button like the first image? Here is my button and spinner .xml

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/window_recent_menu"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_btn"
    android:contentDescription="@string/contentDesc"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<Spinner android:id="@+id/window_recent_menu_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Thanks

P.S the `android:visibility="gone"` for the ImageButton is for certain views. That does not apply for the view seen above.

Comment: Isn´t the design pattern of a spinner to show in the middle of the screen?

Comment: Why not use the proper Action Bar!?

Comment: @PaulBurke because I want a custom Action Bar so I created this view.

Comment: @hakanostrom Im not sure if it is the design. I am trying the popupmenu now

Answer (score 0):

What you really want here is a [`PopupMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html), not a `Spinner`. ([support package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html))